# make sure that you have the appropriate privileges to create this folder. (0x2) error

Tags: wine

Since the last few days WINE is not running well (it worked for me before).
When I try to install something(Photoshop/winamp) it says

```
folder 'C:\windows' could not be created
make sure that you have the appropriate privileges to create this folder. (0x2)
```

or it says

```
Error writing temporary file. Make sure that your temp folder is valid
```

When I try to install Photoshop it says

```
Setup has experienced an error.

Please do the following:
   -close any running program
   -Empty your temporary folder
   -Check our internet connection(But internet is always connected in my Laptop)
Then try to run the setup again
```

And also I can't remove any program (that I installed before) form wine, it has no response whether i click on it or not.

So what can I do now to fix this problem (I also reinstalled WINE, but the same problem occurs). I am using wine-1.6.1

Comment: Simply Photoshop is not installing

Answer (score 0):

You may like to remove your wineprefix instead. Just do:

```
mv .wine/ wine.bk/
```

And try again.

Answer (score 0):

If you can run winetricks,delete the selected app and reinstall.